# How to count the number of occurrences of something in one month

Tags: sql-server

I want to count the number of people that voted in same month

I have table the looks like:

```
Table_votes
    ID
    Person_ID
    voteitem_ID
    vote
    Date
```

Data in the table would look like:

```
1  1  1  2/2/2012
2  1  2  2/2/2012
3  2  1  3/3/2012
4  2  2  3/3/2012
5  3  1  2/12/2012
6  3  2  2/12/2012
```

what i want the Query to out put is that 2 people voted in month 2 and 1 person voted in month 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(person_id) as person_count
       month(Date) as Month
from table_votes
group by month(Date)
```

Comment: the only thing i did to this was select count(distinct person_id)

Answer (score 1):

if your data has more than one year, you'll need to take that into account.

try

```
select 
 count(distinct person_id) as count_personID,
 year(date) as yr,
 month(date) as mo
from
 table_votes
group by
 year(date),
 month(date)
```